# Filemaker multiple many-to-one/many-to-many relationship from one table to another

Tags: many-to-many, relationship, filemaker

Imagine the following; i have an record  in one table representing an service. Another table with user accounts. The Service record has two fields where in the first an tech user and in the second an billing user can get selected.

```
            / - Contact Tech -\
   SERVICE -                   -> USER
            \ - Contact Bill -/
```

How can this get designed in filemaker 14? When i try to design this, Tech and Bill are always equal. If i change one the other gets changed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear. Please explain in more detail what is being tracked here.

On the surface, it seems that Users subscribe to Services. This would be a many-to-many relationship, as each user can subscribe to multiple services, while each service can be provided to multiple users. To resolve this you would require three tables:

```
Users -< Subscriptions >- Services
```

The Subscriptions table would hold an individual record for each instance of a user subscribing to a service (this is known as a *join table*).  The contact details would be fields in the Subscriptions table.

Comment: As far as I understand OP, this seems to be the correct solution.It's actually not FileMaker-specific, but a simple many to many relation that could exist in any database.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to the same table as many times as you want. Use a deferent Foreign key to link each user.

E.g. use fk_UserID_Tech to link the first user and fk_UserID_billing for the second user. In the "define database" you can link to another instance of the same table, so your diagram will look like this:

```
           / - Contact Tech   ->  USER_Teck
   SERVICE -                   
            \ - Contact Bill  ->  User_Bill
```

Both instances - USER_Teck and User_Bill are the instances of the same table - Users. They are called Table Occurrences.